# Using while statement to divide and print

Tags: loops, while-loop

looking at a revision question from a past paper.

The question asks write a while loop to print out the following values 6,12,18,24,30,36

Here is the code i have wrote (pen and paper as ive no compiler at present, im on mobile)

```
int i = 6;
        while (i < 40){
           if (i % 6 == 0)
            i++;
       System.out.println(i) ;
        }
```

would this be the correct answer tot he question, PS this is not homework, its exam revision

Comment: More efficient would be: while (i < 40) { System.out.println(i); i += 6; }

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just do

```
int i=6;
    while(i<=36);
    System.out.println(i+=6); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, the question asks for the while loop. my previous question asked for a for loop to print out devision of 2.for(int x = 1; x <20; x++){
            if (x % 2 == 0){System.out.println(x);}
        }

Answer (score 0):

you want `System.out.println(i++);`

as

```
i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

will print 7,13,19,25,31,37.